# using sharepoint 2010 FBA with different webapplications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I'm migrating an existing SharePoint 2007 FBA Single Sign ON  Solution to SharePoint 2010.

I have three different webapplication all with the same custom membershipprovider.

In the validateUser methode I need to check from which application the user is authenticated.
Since I have just one provider configured in the web.config of the sts, I'm not able to get the applicationName from the provider.

Is there a way to get the webapplicationname whitout setting different providers for each application?

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJGcy.png

I Want to know the application names from app A,B,C in the validateUser methode.